# Best way to creating a temptable with data updated in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

I am updating a permanent table and I need to have another temp table with those records which have been updated in the permanent table. What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
UPDATE PTable
SET ...
OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO #TableIAlreadyCreated
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, or use triggers for such a task.